# Что я делаю не так? Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "password"

Tags: symfony4, symfony-form

Сущность [1]

```
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", nullable=true, length=128, options={"comment":"Пароль пользователя"})
 * @Assert\Regex(
 * pattern="/^[0-9A-Za-z-]+$/",
 * message="Пароль может содержать только латинские буквы A-z, цифры 0-9 и тире"
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=8,
 *     max=24,
 *     minMessage="Длина пароля не соответствует минимальным требованиям. Min: 8, Мах: 24",
 *     maxMessage="Длина пароля не соответствует минимальным требованиям. Min: 8, Мах: 24")
 */
private $password;
```

Форма[2]

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Имя',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Введите имя'
            )))

        ->add('phone', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Телефон',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Введите телефон'
            )))
        ->add('email', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Email',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Введите email'
            )))
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'label' => 'Новый пароль',
            'required' => false,
            'invalid_message' => 'Поля паролей должны совпадать',
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'Новый пароль',  'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Не менее 8 символов',

            )),
            'attr' => [
                'autocomplete' => 'off'
            ],
            'second_options' => array(
                'label' => 'Повторите новый пароль',
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Не менее 8 символов',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off'
                ))));
}
```

twig[3]

```
   {% for passwordField in form_user.password %}
                    <div>
                        <span>{{ passwordField.vars.label }} </span>
                        {{ form_widget(passwordField) }}
                        <div class="form-error">
                            {{ form_errors(passwordField) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Обработка[4]

```
if ($form_user->isSubmitted() && $form_user->isValid()) {
        $user = $form_user->getData();
        // Проверяем изменялся ли пароль
        if ($user->getPassword()) {
            // Меняем соль и генерируем пароль
            $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', true, 10);
            $user->setSalt(md5(time()));
            $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt()));
        } else {
            // Возвращаем старое значение пароля
            $user->setPassword($originPassword);
        }
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
```

Не пойму что делаю не так, пытаюсь сохранить форму без ввода пароля, это форма редактирования пользователя.
Алгоритм таков, если пользователь не ввел пароль и отправил форму, то вставляем в форму старый пароль[4].

Раньше вроде такой код работал, но сейчас даже не знаю что не так.

Выдает ошибку

```
Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "password".
```

Как можно это обойти?

Comment: Нашел такой же вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100528/expected-argument-of-type-string-null-given-at-property-path
но не сработал для меня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в моей сущности[1], а именно в методе setPassword

Раньше было

```
public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}
```

Рабочий вариант

```
public function setPassword(?string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}
```